# Unexpected output of OpenSSL AES_ctr128_encrypt() as pseudo-random function for key derivation in RFC3711 (SRTP)

Tags: c++, openssl, aes

I'm trying to implement a simple version of the pseudo-random function defined in **RFC3711 (Secure RTP protocol)**, which is **AES in counter mode with a 128-bit master key**.

I'm using a 32-bit Intel Core2Duo CPU (LittleEndian) and **OpenSSL v0.9.8**'s `AES_ctr128_encrypt()`.

As instructed by RFC3711 for key derivation I only need to do a single call to `AES_ctr128_encrypt()` and provide:

1. The concatenation of a known 112-bit (14-byte) Input Vector and a 16-bit (2-byte) counter initialized to zero
2. A known 128-bit master key

...to yield exactly 16 bytes of ciphertext (e.g. the encryption key).

I'm using the sample test vector for encryption key derivation provided in **Appendix B.3 of RFC3711** -- in a pinch this sums up to the following:

128-bit Master Key :  `E1F97A0D3E018BE0D64FA32C06DE4139`

112-bit Input Vector: `0EC675AD498AFEEBB6960B3AABE6`

16-bit counter: `0000`

When feeding the concatenation of the 112-bit Input Vector and 16-bit counter into AES_ctr128_encrypt() I am **NOT** getting the expected output that **Appendix B.3 of RFC3711 is listing**.

The expected ciphertext output (according to Appendix B.3 of RFC3711) should be:
`C61E7A93744F39EE10734AFE3FF7A087`

The actual ciphertext output I get with my code is: 
`C8D80F3E3DC5C705A6E541C49411A087`

(NOTE that **only the last 16 bits are as expected**).

**Why is that?  What am I doing wrong?**

Here's the code I have:

```
// COMPILE WITH:
// g++ -o aesctr128 -lcrypto aesctr128_test.cpp

#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct counter_state 
{ 
    unsigned char ivec[16];   // ivec[0..13] (high-order bytes) is 'IV' / ivec[14..15] (low-order bytes) is 'counter'
    unsigned int num;         // Block byte offset
    unsigned char ecount[16]; 
}; 

int reset_state(struct counter_state *state, const unsigned char iv[14])
{   
    // aes_ctr128_encrypt() requires 'num' and 'ecount' to be set to zero on its first call
    state->num = 0; 
    memset(state->ecount, 0, 16);      

    // Clear BOTH 14 high-order bytes [0..13] for 'IV' *AND* 2 low-order bytes [14..15] for 'counter'
    memset(state->ivec, 0, 16);
    // Copy 'IV' into 14 high-order bytes [0..13] -- 2 low-order bytes [14..15] remain zero
    memcpy(state->ivec, iv, 14);

    return 0;
} 

int pseudorandom_function2()
{
    int rc = 0;
    AES_KEY aes_key;
    struct counter_state state;
    unsigned char key[16];         // Master key (16-byte -- 128 bits)
    unsigned char iv[14];          // Input vector (14-byte -- 112 bits)
    unsigned char x[16];           // 16-byte concatenation of 14-byte Input Vector and 2-byte counter (00)
    unsigned char out[16];         // 16-byte encrypted ciphertext

    memset(key, 0, sizeof(key));
    key[0] = 0xE1;
    key[1] = 0xF9;
    key[2] = 0x7A;
    key[3] = 0x0D;
    key[4] = 0x3E;
    key[5] = 0x01;
    key[6] = 0x8B;
    key[7] = 0xE0;
    key[8] = 0xD6;
    key[9] = 0x4F;
    key[10] = 0xA3;
    key[11] = 0x2C;
    key[12] = 0x06;
    key[13] = 0xDE;
    key[14] = 0x41;
    key[15] = 0x39;

    memset(iv, 0, sizeof(iv));
    iv[0] = 0x0E;
    iv[1] = 0xC6;
    iv[2] = 0x75;
    iv[3] = 0xAD;
    iv[4] = 0x49;
    iv[5] = 0x8A;
    iv[6] = 0xFE;
    iv[7] = 0xEB;
    iv[8] = 0xB6;
    iv[9] = 0x96;
    iv[10] = 0x0B;
    iv[11] = 0x3A;
    iv[12] = 0xAB;
    iv[13] = 0xE6;

    memset(x, 0, sizeof(x));
    memcpy(x, iv, 14);

    // Initialize encryption KEY
    rc = AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &aes_key);
    if (rc < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    reset_state(&state, iv);

    memset(out, 0, sizeof(out));

    printf("ivec BEFORE: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      printf("%02x", state.ivec[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Encrypt given x input using key to out
    AES_ctr128_encrypt(x, out, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, &aes_key, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);

    for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) 
    {
        printf("pseudorandom_function2: out[%d] = %02x\n", k, out[k]);
    }

    printf("ivec  AFTER: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      printf("%02x", state.ivec[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    pseudorandom_function2();
    return 0;
}
```

Actual output on my screen:

```
ivec BEFORE: 0ec675ad498afeebb6960b3aabe60000
pseudorandom_function2: out[0] = c8
pseudorandom_function2: out[1] = d8
pseudorandom_function2: out[2] = 0f
pseudorandom_function2: out[3] = 3e
pseudorandom_function2: out[4] = 3d
pseudorandom_function2: out[5] = c5
pseudorandom_function2: out[6] = c7
pseudorandom_function2: out[7] = 05
pseudorandom_function2: out[8] = a6
pseudorandom_function2: out[9] = e5
pseudorandom_function2: out[10] = 41
pseudorandom_function2: out[11] = c4
pseudorandom_function2: out[12] = 94
pseudorandom_function2: out[13] = 11
pseudorandom_function2: out[14] = a0
pseudorandom_function2: out[15] = 87
ivec  AFTER: 0ec675ad498afeebb6960b3aabe60001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
memcpy(x, iv, 14);
```

isn't supposed to be there. Remove it. Doing so, leaving everything else in your code as-is:

**Output**

```
ivec BEFORE: 0ec675ad498afeebb6960b3aabe60000
pseudorandom_function2: out[0] = c6
pseudorandom_function2: out[1] = 1e
pseudorandom_function2: out[2] = 7a
pseudorandom_function2: out[3] = 93
pseudorandom_function2: out[4] = 74
pseudorandom_function2: out[5] = 4f
pseudorandom_function2: out[6] = 39
pseudorandom_function2: out[7] = ee
pseudorandom_function2: out[8] = 10
pseudorandom_function2: out[9] = 73
pseudorandom_function2: out[10] = 4a
pseudorandom_function2: out[11] = fe
pseudorandom_function2: out[12] = 3f
pseudorandom_function2: out[13] = f7
pseudorandom_function2: out[14] = a0
pseudorandom_function2: out[15] = 87
ivec  AFTER: 0ec675ad498afeebb6960b3aabe60001
```

Comment: Wow!  Indeed!  I had been looking to understand this for so long now.  Thanks!  So from this I take it that the actual "input" value used by AES_ctr128_encrypt() is its 5th parameter (ivec).  So what is the 1st parameter (in) really used for? And why must it be 0?  (I thought the counter was the low-order bytes of the 5th parameter (ivec)...?